# Return statement in test method

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

How should I correctly return element in my test method. I have problem in my test.

```
when(teamService.createTeam(teamDto)).thenReturn();
```

In this line i don't know how to wrote correctly return statement.What should be in bracket after thenReturn.
My method cretate team look like this:

```
@Transactional
    public Team createTeam(TeamDto teamDto) {
        Assert.notNull(teamDto, "Object can't be null!");
        try {
            Assert.notNull(teamDto.getName());
            return teamRepository.save(modelMapper.map(teamDto, Team.class));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new CreateEntityException(e);
        }
    }
```

And in this method i return Team object but when i add Team i have expression expected.

Comment: Put what you want `createTeam` to return when it will be called .

Answer (score 3):

depending on what you want to do, you could either do:

```
when(teamService.createTeam(teamDto)).thenReturn(new Team());
```

or

```
Team team = mock(Team.class);
when(teamService.createTeam(teamDto)).thenReturn(team);
```

PS: I am assuming that your class under test is NOT the one containing the method you have posted. I am assuming that you are mocking that service, so somewhere, before, you should have written something like:

```
TeamService teamService = mock(TeamService.class);
```

Comment: Thank's taht what i Want!!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a mocking framework to mock your TeamService class, you should create a mock `Team` object with dummy values and return it in the `thenReturn()` clause.